Identify SMD part marked "QO 11" or "Q0 11" (zero)
I have a SMD part with probably mark "QO 11" or "Q0(zero) 11" on it, and its package is SOT89. I doubt its KTB1260 PNP transistor, but in measuring with diode mode of multimeter it shows number 1.4 between emitter and collector pins and its not open circuit, and .59 from collector to base and .8 from emitter to base, and these numbers doesn't match a PNP transistor. I couldn't find any part number and datasheet for it, does anybody have information for that part number?



The picture didn't get attached, it seems

It's clearly a zero

I think it could be a shunt regulator too

From the Turuta SMD-codes Databook, an SOT-89 device with code QO is, indeed, the KTB1260-O PNP transistor that you suspected. The code Q0 is not listed, but similar-looking codes that could easily be mistaken are QG and QQ. These correspond to another KTB1260 variant and one of two NPN transistors, respectively:

The fact that you're getting unexpected voltage drops across the terminals could point to a defective chip. Do you have any others to compare with, or just the one chip?

Thanks, i had one of it that was well and numbers that i said is for the healthy and valid one

Pictures are from two separate parts and the code we see is probably correct

It's possibly an onsemi (formerly Sanyo) PCP1208 NPN transistor.

The pictures I found of this part look a bit different then the one you posted here, but since the part is old and had multiple manufacturers, I think it's possible they changed over time.

Thanks for your reply
But it's not NPN tr according to numbers meter shows, i wonder why collector and emitter pins shows 1.4 if it's a KTB1260 PNP transistor
